# can not upload .php file with php fle uploader

Tags: php, file-upload, php-5.6

I am currently facing a problem with the php file uploader `move_uploaded_file`

I tried it with an image and its working perfectly. The file gets uploaded to the target folder. But as soon as i try to upload a .php file it just doesn't work anymore. I want to set up a File Upload for a .php file which is only available on a closed network which is not reachable from the internet.

My PHP Script for the upload Test is very basic:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
$target_dir = "../src/contents/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$imageFileType = strtolower(pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
   echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["file"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
   echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
```

The target_dir Folder on my Server is set to 777 Permissions.

I've also checked the Logs. I don't get any entry when uploading a .png oder .jpg file. but i get one when uploading a .php file:

> PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move

Question: Is there something special needed to allow the Upload of a .php File?

**Edit:**
I just found out that there maybe a Problem with the traget_dir
I tried to set it to: $target_dir = "../src/contents/";
This worked for a .png file but not for the .php file.
I tried to set it to $target_dir = "uploads";
This worked for both the .png and the .php file.

Comment: try using absolute paths

Comment: More likely there was “something special” done to _disallow_ this … if not in your code itself, then probably in the PHP/server configuration. Have you checked whether you even _have_ an uploaded file at this moment? (Start with a var_dump of $_FILES)

Comment: Please Remove the double dots here "$target_dir = "../src/contents/";"

Comment: that will work in css not in php. So remove "../src/contents/" replace with exact value "/src/contents/"

Comment: Thank you all for the replies. @siddharthaesunuri i think there is realy something wrong with the "../". the strange thing is: I tried it with $target_dir = "../src/contents/"; and its working with an png file but not with an php file. so i made a new folder $target_dir = "upload/"; just to try it. There both png and php file worked. Strange some how, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

PHP is server side, So it can't go back like JS and CSS do.

For PHP, we have to mention the exact path without "../" it mislead the path for PHP files.

$target_dir = "../src/contents/"; it will work JS and CSS because it is client side.

So remove "../" and give the proper root path. It will work.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Strange part about it is that upload of a .png file to "../src/contens" is working just not with a .php file. I did set to $target_dir = "../contents/"; now. And somehow its working with .png and .php so the "../" is working.